# Nested Drawables

Tags: android

Can I include a drawable inside another drawable?

The backstory is simple - I have a drawable, and I need different color backgrounds for an item, but I want the other properties (corners, stroke, etc.) the same.

Let's say I have this as a base:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 

    <corners 
         android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
          <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF00FF00" />

</shape>
```

Which I then include in another drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 

    <include 
         android:include="@drawable/base" /> 
              <solid android:color="#00000000"/> 

</shape>
```

And if this is not possible, how do manage this kind of thing?